# Flask-whooshalchemy - Changing underlying schema

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, whoosh

Getting the following error when I changed a table column from post_text to post_text1. I've updated my model and search accordingly

```
% (name, schema))
UnknownFieldError: No field named 'post_text1' in <Schema: ['id', 'post_text']>
```

And heres the file:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['post_text1', 'post_text2', 'post_text3']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_type = db.Column(db.String(256))
    post_text1 = db.Column(db.String(256))
    post_text2 = db.Column(db.String(256))
    post_text3 = db.Column(db.String(256))
    post_source = db.Column(db.String(256))
    post_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    number_of_replies = db.Column(db.Integer)
    post_score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    post_rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
    flagged = db.Column(db.Integer)
    admin_post = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    division = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(256))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.post_text1)

    def as_dict(self):
      return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

Suggestions? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it seems the uninstall still kept the old schema.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and was able to fix it by deleting the `whoosh_index` directory that whoosh generates.